# Config file for publishing web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis

I have a Visual Studio web service application with the following solution structure (using VS2013 Community):

```
- [Solution] S
   - [Project] S_Service
      - S.amsx
   - [Project] S_Lib
      - File1.cs 
      - File2.cs
      - app.config
```

The `S_Service` project is a simple web service project, with just a single asmx file with one WebService method.  The project contains a reference to the `S_Lib` project, a class library to do all the work in terms of the business logic (the request processing).

In `S_Lib` I have an `app.config` file in which I store things like directories and file names for stuff which is used by the various components in `S_Lib`.  When I am developing, changes to that file are picked up by the code ok.

Here's the problem: When I publish the `S_Service` project, the publish directory doesn't contain my `app.config` - only `S_Service.dll` and `S_Lib.dll`.  After reading some other posts on StackOverflow (can't seem to find them now), I tried setting the build action on `app.config` to Content and to Copy Always.  Great, this gets the file across to the publish directory, so it looks ok.  But, once I deploy the whole lot onto IIS, any changes to the `app.config` file do not get reflected when the service is run.  In fact I can delete the file completely from the IIS directory and it runs just fine.  It's as though `S_Lib.dll` contains a compiled version of the configuration settings.  This is no use, as I want to modify the config depending on the machine it's deployed on.

What do I need to do so that `app.config` is actually used at runtime and that changes are read on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failing to find a simple Visual Studio-based solution to do what I want, I implemented a more customised solution.  In the library project, I replaced the config lookup method:

```
internal static string GetConfig(string key) {
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] as string;
}
```

with a new method that reads my own settings file (custom format), stored in the solution.  It's not perfectly ideal as it means that each project in the solution has to have its own settings file, but it's simpler overall. If anyone is interested please leave a comment and I will elaborate on this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you wrote, S_Lib.dll contains compiles settings from the time when you set them in VS settings designer. Therefore it is still working (more or less).

You have a web service so you need a web.config. Add one to S_Service project. Then merge app.config content to web.config. Every time you change some setting in S_Lib project you will have to merge changes to web.config as well.

Or you could add app.config to S_Service project **as a link** by name web.config (not sure if it is possible to create a link with different name). Then when you change settings in S_Lib project they will be referenced in S_Service project automatically.

Comment: The first suggestion will do the trick, it's just a shame that there doesn't seem to be a way to do what I want, i.e. the library has it's own config file.  It means I have to parameterise things in S_Lib and pass them in from each client of S_Lib.